# jquery ui tab at both top and bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to have a Jquery UI tab with top and button menu function, is it possible to do that ?
(the content are loaded via ajax ,what i mean is the top tab and bottom tab both at the same time.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({                 
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                }
            },
            cookie: {
                // store cookie for a day, without, it would be a session cookie
                expires: 1
            }
        });
});
</script>
<div id="tabs"> 
    <ul id="top"> 
       <li><a href="top1.php">top 1</a></li> 
       <li><a href="top2.php">top 2</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul id="bottom"> 
       <li><a href="bottom.php">bottom 1</a></li> 
       <li><a href="bottom.php">bottom 2</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you explain *top* and *bottom* buttons (> scroll top and scroll down)? then, show us your code and what you already tried

Comment: what i mean is the top tab and bottom tab both at the same time.
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="top1.php">top 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="top2.php">top 2</a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="bottom.php">bottom 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="bottom.php">bottom 2</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

Comment: you can edit your question by clicking on the appropriate link below your question. Please give as much information as possible (especially what your already tried) so that we could help you

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about what you want to achieve, but if you are trying to make similiar layout as I am in [jQuery UI tabs - how to change tab position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759355/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-change-tab-position/11759804#11759804) ,then if you dont mind having the tabs layout of fixed height, then you can simply move the tabs by css as I did here http://jsfiddle.net/L6QjK/2/

If you DO mind the fixed height, my only idea so far is to create layout with one control panel, than add some `<div>`  looking as control panel and move some tabs after initialization from the code by usinge something like this:

`$("#yourFakeControlPanel").append($(".ui-tabs-nav").find("#yourTab"));`

`$(".ui-tabs-nav").find("#yourTab").remove();`

This was working when all the tabs were static, but I have ran to some errors, when adding new tabs dynamicaly, so consider this as a hint not as an exact answer

Answer (score 0):

I think i have finaly found your answer. Look to my post, I have written there how to make tabs on the top and bottom same time [jQuery UI tabs - how to change tab position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11759355/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-change-tab-position/11818835#11818835)

and if zou find this helpful, mark this as an answer to lead others to the right sollution